# What happen when a user with reputation 1 gets a down vote?

Tags: support, down-votes, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

If a user with reputation 1 gets a down vote, his reputation is not lowered. Are the down-votes considered, when the same user gets some up-votes?

Supposing that a user gets 3 down-votes and 3 up-votes for a question he made, will his reputation be 15 or 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be 15 assuming all the up votes are cast after all the down votes.

Down votes that are made when a user already has the minimum reputation, are simply ignored.

Comment: Yes; I meant that all the down votes are cast before all the up votes.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum possible rep is always 1 in every case.

Comment: This is why if you think you have any idiocy that you really can't control, it's best to get it out of your system right away. :)